# Find the smallest square with a list of tetrominos

Tags: algorithm, tetris

Imagine you have a list of [Tetrominos](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tetromino) (tetris shapes) that cannot rotate (19 possibilities) and you have to arrange them to make the smallest square.

For example, given:

```
A...
A...
A...
A...

BB..
.B..
.B..
....

.C..
.C..
CC..
....
```

The result should be:

```
A.BB
A.CB
A.CB
ACC.
```

as this is the smallest square that can accommodate the three inputs.

I tried to figure it out by myself but now I'm a bit confused.

Do I need to try with a certain size of square, try every possibilities and then increase that square until it's possible to place every Tetromino or is there another way?

Comment: Algorithmic aspects of Tetris are in fact subject of advanced academic study, for instance [here](http://erikdemaine.org/papers/Tetris_TR2002/paper.pdf). It seems to be rather hard.

Comment: "*arrange them to make the smallest square*" - do you mean "*fits within the smallest possible bounds*"? Because a square of length *n* will (at best) fit *n* ^ 2 / 4 Tetrominos.